# Matlab-Simulink 2014 'load' error: MATLAB expression 'load' does not have the correct number of fields

Tags: matlab, save, load, user-defined-functions, simulink

I am using Matlab 2014b. And i am not sure whether it was a problem for older versions but i think it is a new issue.

I want to use my main function as .m file, and I want to set data here. I will use this data in my Simulink Model - User Defined Functions. I call 'save' in m-file after creating data as such:

save('engineProperties.mat')

It creates a .mat file in my current folder. And i use it anywhere i want by:

load('engineProperties.mat')

It usually works fine. However, sometimes I get the following error:

"MATLAB expression 'load' does not have the correct number of fields: expected 8; found 9.
Block calculateEngineLoad (#30)
While executing: State During Action"

As the error message implies, it happens when I add or remove data. I solve it by creating new named .mat file, but it is not feasible because i create lots of .mat file, and sometimes i do not remember the correct one!

Or I solve it by creating dummy variables to re-match the size of data. It is not feasible tough.

Deleting the .mat file from current folder usually not works. But sometimes it works, for example when i restart my computer!

I think it is an easy problem but did not find any similar error in web. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

The code in your MATLAB function block is compiled to C-Code which does not support structs of variable size. Whenever your struct changes, it is required to generate and compile again.

If you just want to fix it, switch to a interpreted MATLAB function block. Be aware that this results in a bad performance in many cases.

Instead I would rethink your architecture. From the file name I assume your file contains some parameters. Instead of loading them in your function block, a much better architecture would be to use block parameters and set them. Then you can continue using a MATLAB function block and there is no need to regenerate code.

Comment: As I understand, you suggest me to use 'Interpreted MATLAB function' as given in Simulink Library Browser. But my user-defined function is somehow long, about 20 line. It is not just a math operation. Can you eleborate what you mean by 'use block parameters'? I think you are very close to my solution

Comment: You can add parameter this way http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameter-arguments-in-matlab-function-block-functions.html

Comment: I will work on it on following weeks. Then I'll let you know whether it is okay to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, adding parameter as you suggested is a  somehow good solution to my problem. But sometimes I really need to save my data to somewhere, and load it from anywhere else. So there should be a direct solution to it

Answer (score 0):

The above suggested solution (given in http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameter-arguments-in-matlab-function-block-functions.html) is good enough. But, sometimes you may have lots of data, and you just do not want to make your function crowded. So here is another solution:

Based on the Daniel's answer, Matlab is compiled to C-Code. And although you don't feel that, it creates some ".mexw64" files. Close your matlab and remove those files. Thats all